# Работа модулей NodeJs: подключение долго выполняемого модуля MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Добрый день! Пробую организовать 1 подключение к MongoDB для всего приложения. Версия модуля MongoDB для NodeJs 3.0. 
Создал соответствующий модуль `mongoConnect.js`. Сам по себе он работает отлично:

```
const mongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient; 
const mongodb = new mongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/");

function mongoConnect(){
        console.log("*****попытка подключения к MongoDB********")
    mongodb.connect((err, client)=>{
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log("*****Подключение к MongoDB прошло успешно********")
            return client;

        });
}
module.exports.mongoConnect = mongoConnect;
```

В другом модуле, пытаюсь найти что-нибудь в БД (оба модуля находятся в 1-й папке):

```
const mongoConnect = require("./mongoConnect.js").mongoConnect();
function find(){
console.log(mongoConnect) //undefined
    db = mongoConnect.db("test");
    db.collection("goods", function(err, collection){
            collection.find().limit(1).toArray(function(err, result){
                console.log(result);
            })
        })
}
setTimeout(find,5000) // т.к. подключение к БД занимает время (до 2х секунд) - устанавливаю задержку в 5 секунд.
```

Итог работы модулей:

```
*****попытка подключения к MongoDB********
*****Подключение к MongoDB прошло успешно********
undefined
C:\Users\user\Desktop\Back-end\myModules\workWithMongodb.js:15
    var db = mongoConnect.db("test");
                          ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'db' of undefined
```

В итоге, ничего не вышло. Как быть в данном случае?

П.С.: проверку на латиницу/кириллицу проводил)

Comment: ... этот комментарий предназначен для того, чтобы привлечь внимание к вопросу)

Answer (score 1):

Я модифицировал ваш пример, чтобы вы поняли суть происходящего. Расставил цифры по порядку, как вы предполагаете, что это работает:

```
const mongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const mongodb = new mongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/");

function mongoConnect(){
  console.log("1. попытка подключения к MongoDB");
  mongodb.connect(function(err, client){
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("2. Подключение к MongoDB прошло успешно");
    return client;
  });
  console.log("3. Эта строчка не должна выполняться");
}

console.log(mongoConnect());
```

Но все совсем иначе. Вот что получилось:

```
1. попытка подключения к MongoDB
3. Эта строчка не должна выполняться
undefined
2. Подключение к MongoDB прошло успешно
```

Таким образом, `mongoConnect` отработала и вернула `undefined`. А блок `mongodb.connect` выполнился, асинхронно, но уже после, и его значение ничему не присвоилось.

Вы не знакомы с асинхронностью в Javascript. Чтобы понять, как она работает, [прочтите про Promise](https://learn.javascript.ru/promise).

В общих чертах, `return` следует заменить на `resolve`, любую ошибку - на `reject`. `then` - блок выполняется после `resolve`, `catch` - выполняется в случае `reject`.

Модифицированная версия вашего скрипта:

```
const mongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const mongodb = new mongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/");

function mongoConnect(){
  console.log("1. попытка подключения к MongoDB");
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    mongodb.connect(function(err, client){
      if (err) {
        reject(new Error(err));
        // return, нужен, так как выполнение кода после reject все равно продолжится
        return;
      }
      console.log("2. Подключение к MongoDB прошло успешно");
      resolve(client);
    });
  });
}

mongoConnect()
// эта часть выполнится после `resolve`
.then(function(result){
  console.log(result);
})
// эта часть выполнится если будет `reject`
.catch(function(error){
  console.log(error);
});
```

В итоге получится следующее:

```
1. попытка подключения к MongoDB
2. Подключение к MongoDB прошло успешно
MongoClient {
...
```

Конструкции `.then` можно насаживать по цепочке, каждая `.then` должна возвращать `Promise`, тогда будет последовательное выполнение частей.

Возможно использовать колбеки, но когда вы начнете делать серьезную систему, и вкладывать колбеки в колбеки, для вас это станет адом.

Советую также ознакомиться в первую очередь с:

- [стрелочные функции](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) - я не стал использовать их в примере
- модуль NodeJS [EventEmitter](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html) - инициацию приложения и общение между его асинхронными частями можно постоить на нем
- [async/await](https://habrahabr.ru/post/334772/)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. В своем ответе - ниже - я по своему решил проблему. Использовал коллбэки.

Comment: Возможно использовать колбеки, но когда вы начнете делать серьезную систему, и вкладывать колбеки в колбеки, для вас это станет адом.

Answer (score 0):

Решая возникшую проблему, придумал вот такую конструкцию. Код упростил для понимания...собственного понимая):

Код подключаемого модуля `2.js`:

```
var rezult;
function two(){
    console.log("work two")
    result = 1+2;
    console.log("result: "+ result);
    return module.exports.two = result;
}

setTimeout(two,1000);
```

запускаемый файл:

```
var two = require("./2.js").two;
function one(){
    console.log("work one")
    var two_2 = require("./2.js").two;
    console.log(two_2+2);
}

setTimeout(one, 2000);
```

Понятия не имею как оно работает, но работает. Писал интуитивно. Насколько это верное решение?

**UPD** Вот моя версия модуля, которой сейчас пользуюсь:
файл `connectMongo.js`

```
const mongoClient =  require("mongodb").MongoClient;

function Mongo () {
    this.open =  function (collectionName){
        this.collection = this.db.collection(collectionName);
        console.log(`Успешное подключение к коллекции:${collectionName}`);
        return this.collection;
    },
    this.close = function (){
        this.client.close();
        console.log("Подключение к Монго закрыто");
        return;
    },
    this.connect = function (options, callback){
        var a = options || {};
        var dbName = a.dbName || "test";
        var thisCallback
        if (typeof options == "function"){
            thisCallback = options;
        }else {
            thisCallback = callback || function(){};
        }
        this.url = a.url || "mongodb://localhost:27017";
        mongoClient.connect(this.url,(err, client)=>{
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log("Подключение к Монго прошло успешно");
            this.db = client.db(dbName);
            this.client = client;
            return thisCallback();
        });
    }
}

module.exports = Mongo;
```

запускаемый файл `app.js`

```
const connectMongoDB = require("./connectMongo.js");
const mongo = new connectMongoDB();
mongo.connect({dbName:"users"}); // при необходимости, можно использовать коллбєк.

let collection = mongo.open("test);
```